# how to use of google captcha multiple times in page?

Tags: php, html, captcha, recaptcha

I have  two forms in my page .I want to implement google captcha in both forms. I tried to implement by using get_html() function in both forms but it display only one captha in my page

```
echo $captcha->get_html();
```

passed public key intenally in google get_html() using interface class.

How can i display captcha in both forms ?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it

```
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
```

The API doesn't include a class, how are you using OOP style code?

Comment: hmm.if u write this line two times in page it load captcha only one time

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the javascript only renders this once per page.

One desperate solution might be to `<iframe>` one or both of the forms?

**EDIT:**
Create a page with the form in html, and access it with `<iframe src="http://site.com/form.html"></iframe>`

Set width and height attributes to desired sizes.

**EDIT (2nd):**
Well basicly you have a php file rendering and handeling the form data in the `<iframe>`. What exactly are you curious about regarding this technique?